# Sidemenu Node-red-dashboard not visible

Tags: dashboard, node-red

in my node-red application, the side-bar toolbar menu is not being displayed. I'm looking for some assistance to resolve this.

When I try to access a simple page, the Sidebar or Sidemenu should appear on the leftside of the page. But no Sidebar or Sidemenu is displayed.

My environment is:

> ```
> Node-RED-Dashboard version: 2.15.5
> Node-RED version: v0.20.6
> node.js version: 10.16
> npm version: 9.9.0
> Platform / OS: Raspberry pi 3
> Browser: Chromium 72.0.36
> ```

I remotely accessed the service through my local machine using Firefox 67.02 on Mac OS

Comment: It is advisable that you edit the original post to add images instead of creating an answer to add this kind of information. As suggested below change the configuration inside the red box to  `Always show side menu` , redeploy the flow and test.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the sidebar in the dashboard. You have a configuration option in the editor. Change it from `CLick to show side menu` to `Always show side menu`.

[image]